# Can you create a project without programming files in Virtual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

So I have this web application solution.  I also want to include Google Chrome Portable in the solution, but I want it to be a separate project to help organizing my code.  Is there anyway to create a project to just include a bunch of files without any programming files?  When the project is built, I would also like a BAT file to be ran.

EDIT:  I would also like to include a file result from the Google Chrome Portable project into my web application everytime it is built.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create a new empty project (I chose to make an Win32 Console Application as a library).  Then, under `Project Properties -> Custom Build Step` you can provide a `Command Line` to run.

Comment: The project isn't really empty... it still have a main... but say that I overlook that.  Do you know how I can include file from this project into my web application project when they are built?

Comment: I am primarily a Windows C developer so I don't know about the web application portion but you can create a new `Library` (instead of `Application` or `DLL`) and you don't need to have a `main`.  The project should be empty.

Comment: Earlier I told you to build a `Static Library (.lib)` under `Properties -> Configuration Type`.  Instead, if you make the type `Utility`, neither the compiler or linker should be invoked and you can still make `Build Events`.

Comment: Where is this "Utility" project located?  I can't find it in any of the Project Type categories.

Comment: Right click on the project in question->Properties->Configuration Properties->General->Configuration Type needs to be st to Utility.  I am using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition.